# Best practice to manage date and days

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, date-manipulation

I am working on a project where I have many operations to manage.
Each operation have an end date and is composed by a certain amount of tasks.

I want to display reminders (*a text displayed on the screen*) if a task is not done before `[end date]` - `X days`.

All the data is stored in **MySQL** database and I work with **PHP** and **HTML5**.

- Which datatype is (*are*) the best to work with date and days (*to
  perform calculations*)?
- Can I work with `Date()` and subtract days in a easy way?

I do not have a specific technical question, but I think sharing best way to proceed is a good thing, right?

I'm curious to know what are the best ways to proceed and open to any proposal!

Comment: Research `timestamp` and `datetime` column types. Also, google for `php Carbon` - it's a library using PHP's `DateTime`. End result is you having a few lines of code that perform exactly what you asked for.

Comment: `DATETIME` should be used in MySQL and `new \DateTime()` in PHP. MySQL allows you to use `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` functions and PHP has `\DateInterval()`, combinations allow you everything one could need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to store your date in mysql at field **timestamp** because you can use default value **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP** - it very helpful,
and i think you shouldn't worry about it, there is a plenty of functions::

mysql:

```
select now();
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2015-04-08 12:13:18 |
+---------------------+
select now() - interval 1 day;
+------------------------+
| now() - interval 1 day |
+------------------------+
| 2015-04-07 12:13:29    |
+------------------------+
select now() - interval 7 day;
+------------------------+
| now() - interval 7 day |
+------------------------+
| 2015-04-01 12:13:38    |
+------------------------+
select now() - interval 1 month;
+--------------------------+
| now() - interval 1 month |
+--------------------------+
| 2015-03-08 12:13:58      |
+--------------------------+
```

php:

```
<?php
var_export([
    date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('now')),
    date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('- 1 day')),
    date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('- 7 day')),
    date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('- 1 month')),
]);
/*
Result:

array (
  0 => '2015-04-08 15:15:42',
  1 => '2015-04-07 15:15:42',
  2 => '2015-04-01 15:15:42',
  3 => '2015-03-08 15:15:42',
)
*/
```

And sometimes very helpful to create table like:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

in result your field ts will be automatically seted and updated...

Answer (score 1):

You can store dates as [DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) in your database.

Then in PHP convert it to manageable data using [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and the [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) functions

Answer (score 0):

The best data type to work with is the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class.

In order to perform substractions using the DateTime class, you'll need to use the [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) class.

You'll need some time to get on your ease using those two classes but it will make formatting or date operations easier afterwoods.